# List subversion repositories

Tags: html, svn

How do I list all my subversion repositories on a html page?
All repositories are located in a root folder.

I want to list them as a link list to get a overview of my repositories and to have easy access to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Apache httpd.conf try:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn

  # any "/svn/foo" URL will map to a repository /usr/local/svn/foo
  SVNParentPath /usr/local/svn
</Location>
```

See [redbean](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.apache)

Where /usr/local/svn becomes your repository parent folder.

Edit: I'm assuming that you use a dedicated folder  for the single purpose of locating your repositories ie. you don't put anything else in there.

Comment: If you add "SVNListParentPath on" to this section the /svn url will show a list of the available repositories.

Comment: Won't this simply show all the directories in that location whether they are valid repositories or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out this link:

http://blog.platinumsolutions.com/node/76

We use WebSVN and it works very well.