# Ubuntu Subversion with Windows Client

Tags: windows, eclipse, subclipse

I installed subversion on my Ubuntu server and I can use subclipse (1.6) in Eclipse Helios on Ubuntu and it works fine.

However when I try and use Subclipse (1.6) in Eclipse Helios on Windows, it doesn't work and I get errors.
In Windows when I use `http://serverAddress/svn`, I get an error saying folder doesn't exist and an error in the console saying:

```
Repository has been moved
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'http://serverAddress/svn/'; please relocate
```

When I use `svn://serverAddress/svn`, I get an issue as well.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an Eclipse issue, but a SVN issue.

If you could see your repo in a web browser, the [SVN FAQ mentions an httpd.conf error](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#http-301-error).  But in your case:

- either you haven't created a repository yet (see [`svnadmin create`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html))
- or you have a repo, but haven't create properly a directory in it, [a bit like in this thread](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=2423):

> > I then created a subdirectory "`projectx`" under `~/webapps/svn` with subdirectories "`trunk`", "`branches`" etc and then ran:

```
$ svn import projectx file:///home/<user>/webapps/svn/projectx -m "first import".
```

> > `projectx/trunk` etc showed up fine on Trac, and `https://svn.<user>.webfactional.com/projectx/` showed up fine in the browser, with proper authentication etc. All well and good.
> >
> > However, when attempting to check out the project from trunk (using Tortoise SVN), I got this error:

```
Command: Checkout from https://svn.<user>.webfactional.com/projectx/trunk, revision HEAD, Fully recursive, Externals included  
Error: Repository moved permanently to   
Error: 'http://svn.<user>.webfactional.com/projectx/trunk/'; please relocate
```

With the solution being:

> You've created directories on the filesystem below your repo, eg `~/webapps/svn/projectx`. That's the wrong way.
>
> You should instead use **['`svn mkdir`'](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.mkdir.html)** to create the directories.

---

If this is not enough, see also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068291/repo-browser-in-svn-repository-moved-permanently-to-please-relocate), where it mentions that the repository address is usually `http://servername/svn/repositoryname`, not  `http://servername/svn`.

Comment: Thank you very much! When i change it to http://servername/svn/repository name I can then load the project that is already on. 
Is there a way though to view all of the projects in the svn and then choose one? I can do it in my ubunutu boot but not windows

Comment: @cninden: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747898/list-subversion-repositories if it help you with list all your repositories.